# Missing Angular controller depending on Angular version

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

So I have this source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function commentController($scope) {
            $scope.reportComments = [{ Name:"Frank", Comment:"Booka" }, { Name:"Frank2", Comment:"Booka2" }];
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="" ng-controller="commentController">
            <ul>
              <li ng-repeat="c in reportComments">
                {{ c.Name + ', ' + c.comment }}
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

And it works great.

But then I change the version of AngularJS to 1.3.0 and I get this error:

> Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'loadCommentsController' is not a function,
>   got undefined
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.7/ng/areq?p0=loadCommentsController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
>       at file:///C:/Users/micah_000/Desktop/comment_testbed/js/angular.js:63:12
>       at assertArg (file:///C:/Users/micah_000/Desktop/comment_testbed/js/angular.js:1575:11)
>       at assertArgFn (file:///C:/Users/micah_000/Desktop/comment_testbed/js/angular.js:1585:3)
>       at file:///C:/Users/micah_000/Desktop/comment_testbed/js/angular.js:8416:9
>       at file:///C:/Users/micah_000/Desktop/comment_testbed/js/angular.js:7590:34
>       at forEach (file:///C:/Users/micah_000/Desktop/comment_testbed/js/angular.js:331:20)
>       at nodeLinkFn (file:///C:/Users/micah_000/Desktop/comment_testbed/js/angular.js:7577:11)
>       at compositeLinkFn (file:///C:/Users/micah_000/Desktop/comment_testbed/js/angular.js:7073:13)
>       at publicLinkFn (file:///C:/Users/micah_000/Desktop/comment_testbed/js/angular.js:6952:30)
>       at file:///C:/Users/micah_000/Desktop/comment_testbed/js/angular.js:1449:27

Why?

How can my controller function not be defined?

This treks closely with this [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_intro_controller). If a simple tutorial breaks between releases, it makes the framework look volatile/mercurial/unreliable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ability to use global functions as controllers was deprecated in 1.3.0: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9662. This "feature" doesn't really make sense outside of simple (and unrealistic) demos.

You should define controllers on your Angular module:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
        angular.module('test', [])
          .controller('commentController', function commentController($scope) {
                $scope.reportComments = [
                  { Name:"Frank", Comment:"Booka" }, 
                  { Name:"Frank2", Comment:"Booka2" }
                ];
           });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="test" ng-controller="commentController">
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="c in reportComments">
            {{ c.Name + ', ' + c.comment }}
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>      
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks. Would be great if the surfacing error mentioned this, but I guess the angular source would be less 'lean and mean'.